# double free or corruption in multithreaded program

Tags: c, pthreads, free

I am having a problem

> Error in `./thread': double free or corruption (out): 0x00000000021bb030

my program's purpose is input : # of thread(argv[1]) and read data.txt 100 integer and each thread sorting. in now

my whole code is there..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *bubble(void *data){

    int * arr = data;   
    int i,j,tmp;
    int size = (sizeof(arr)/4);
    printf("%d",size);

    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        for(j=0;j<size-1;){
            if(arr[j]>arr[j+1])
            {
                tmp = arr[j];
                arr[j]=arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1]=tmp;
            }

        }

    }

    for(i=0;i<size;i++) printf("%d ",arr[i]);
        printf("\n");
    return ((void *)0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    FILE * fd;
    int data[100];

    int i,j;
    int tcount = atoi(argv[1]);
    int n = 100/tcount;
    int cursor=0;
    int err;


    pthread_t *thread_t = (pthread_t *)malloc(tcount* sizeof(pthread_t));

    int **data3 = (int **)malloc(tcount *sizeof(int*));
    for( i=0; i<tcount; i++)
        data3[i] = (int *)malloc((100/tcount) *sizeof(int));


    fd = fopen("data.txt", "r");

    printf("tcount = %d n=%d\n",tcount,n);
    for(i =0; i<100;i++)
    {
        fscanf(fd, "%d",&data[i]);
        printf("%d ", data[i]);
    }

    for(j=0;j<tcount;j++){
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            data3[j][i]=data[n*j+i];
            printf("%d ",data3[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    for(i =tcount; i>0;i--)
    {
        err=pthread_create(&thread_t[i],NULL,bubble,(void *)&data3[i]);
            if(err != 0)
                printf("creat thread error");
    }




    for(int i=0; i<tcount; i++)
        free(data3[i]);
    free(data3);
    free(thread_t);
    fclose(fd);

}
```

Comment: This `int size = (sizeof(arr)/4);` does not calculate the size of the array to which's 1st element `arr` points. Hint `arr` is a pointer not an array. A minimal debugging effort would have revealed this.

Comment: `for(i =tcount; i>0;i--)` starts at `tcount`

Answer (score 1):

You create the threads, then immediately start freeing the memory used by the threads without waiting for them to exit. You then also exit the process before the threads might have exited, killing them.

You should wait for the threads to exit before cleaning up and exiting the program. You do that by calling `pthread_join`:

```
for(int i=0; i<tcount; i++)
    pthread_join(thread_t[i]);
```

And as told in a comment `sizeof(arr)` will not give you the size of the array. It will give you the size of the *pointer* and not what it points to.

Furthermore your thread-creation loop start by going out of bounds which will lead to *undefined behavior*. The highest index is `tcount - 1` the the lowest index is `0`.

Lastly a couple of small notes: First is about the naming of the `thread_t` variable. The `_t` suffix is usually used for type-aliases, like e.g. `pthread_t`. While it's not wrong it might confuse readers of your code. The second is that a null pointer in C is represented by `NULL`. Don't use `(void *) 0` (it's not portable).

Comment: So thank about answering my question. i want to get sizeof(arr). how?
And, i am having problem no more execution after  for(j=0;j<tcount;j++){
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            data3[j][i]=data[n*j+i];
            printf("%d ",data3[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } 

plz tell me why..

Comment: @HERIUN Unfortunately you can't get the size, other than passed as an argument. The solution is to not pass the pointer to the array, but a (dynamically allocated) structure containing both the pointer and the size.